# How to loop and save values in new matrix

Tags: matlab, loops, matrix

I have the following code which identifies the velocity values at different values of `KK`.

```
load('Vq.mat')
KK=1;
ft = fftshift(fft2(Vq));
kx = [-70:1:70];
ky = [-70:1:70];
for i1=1:length(kx)
    for i2=1:length(ky)
        kh(i1,i2)=sqrt(kx(i1).^2+ky(i2).^2);
        if (kh(i1,i2)>KK && kh(i1,i2)<KK+1)

        else
            ft(i1,i2)=0;
        end

    end
end
K=sum(ft);
```

So, when I set the value of `KK` as 1 the code will then loop through the matrix `kh` and find the locations where `KK = 1` and grab the velocity at that location (through the if statement). The code then zeros all the other values in the `ft` matrix and only keeps the velocity values at `KK = 1`. I then sum these values to create `K`.

My problem is that I want to loop through `KK` values from `1:70`.
So when `KK = 2`, the code would again loop through `kh` and identify the velocities at `KK = 2`. It would then sum these values and then add to the matrix `K`.

At the end the single matrix of K should include all the sums of the individual values  found at different values of KK

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vi6un5jyby7akej/Vq.mat?dl=0
This is the link to the data file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code is greatly simplified. The main idea is that you find the indices (`inds`) of `kh` values that are between `KK` and `KK+1` using `find` builtin function and sum the corresponding `ft` values at the same indices. You repeat this algorithm for all values of `KK` and add all the computed sums.

```
load('Vq.mat')
ft = fftshift(fft2(Vq));
kx = -70:70;
ky = -70:70;
kh = sqrt(kx.^2 + ky.^2.'); % compute kh only once

sumK = 0;       % accumulate sum for each KK
for KK = 1:70   % loop over all kk values
    inds = find(kh > KK & kh < KK+1);
    sumK = sumK + sum(ft(inds));
end
disp(sumK)      % 267.85 - 2.8089e-14i
```

look how vectorization simplified the code and made it run faster. For example, I created the `kh` matrix only once outside the loop instead of calculating it 70 times. Also using vectorized builtin functions like `find` greatly improves the performance and readability of the code vs. `if` conditions and `for` loops. This is how idiomatiic MATLAB code should be written for conciseness and speed.

**Update:** This is the updated answer after comments from OP:

```
load('Vq.mat')
ft = fftshift(fft2(Vq));
kx = -70:70;
ky = -70:70;
kh = sqrt(kx.^2 + ky.^2.'); % compute kh only once

K = zeros(70,141);    % accumulate sum for each KK
for KK = 1:70         % loop over all kk values
    K(KK,:) = sum( ft .* (kh > KK & kh < KK+1) );
end
```

This is how `K` looks at the end (`spy(K)`):

[image]

Comment: This definitely simplifies the code I had written significantly. **K** should be a matrix of the same size as `kh`. What I was trying to do: so for when `KK=1` I identify the velocities and keep this values and set everything else to zero. I then sum these to create aa row vector. The row vector is important as it sums the identified velocities but also fill-ins in the empty vector with zeros which are needed.

Comment: I want to then do this whole procedure for `KK=2` which will then create another row vector when I sum after finding the velocities. I want all these row vectors in a single matrix and it should be the same size as `kh` as there will be cells with velocities and the rest will be filled with zeros. @aboammar

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear to me. `K` cannot have same size as `kh` because for each value of `KK = 1:70`, you will create a row vector `aa` of size `1x141` which comes from `sum(ft)`. So, after all 70 `KK` values are finished, you'll get `K` of size `70x141` matrix. Please elaborate on this point, specifically, how each row of `K` is created in each iteration of `KK` from 1 to 70.

Comment: you are 100% right. In my own mind I have confused myself. The row vector which you call aa is what I need to save after each iteration of `KK`. So after all 70 `KK` values, you'll get `K` of size `70x141`. This is exactly what I need. I need that final matrix of `K`, which is `70x141`

Comment: @ShahzadMuhammadSarwar - Please see my update. The tricky line `ft .* (kh > KK & kh < KK+1)` will set all `ft` values to zero except those corresponding to `KK` value and you take the sum of that.

Comment: Excellent this is exactly what I needed. This is 100% more efficient than my attempt. Thank you so much.